Caching expensive operations across pages being built in a static build on Next.js
When using generateStaticParams to specify pages to be built statically, and those pages rely on an expensive operation, how do I cache the result of that operation across all page builds?  cache and unstable_cache don't work, and the pages appear to be built twice when doing an npm run build.
This repo has a minimal example.  The function whose value I want to cache is something like this:
import { cache } from 'react';
// import { unstable_cache as cache } from 'next/cache';


export const getDataForCard = cache(async (id: string) => {
  console.log('>>>>>IN cached getDataForCard', id);
  // Imagine an expensive database operation 
  const cardData = { id: id };
  return cardData;
});


Unfortunately the line IN cached getDataForCard is displayed multiple times per id.
Does anyone know how I can cache those at compile time?  I would like the getDataForCard to be called exactly once for every id.
PS. It's actually a Firestore fetch.  I can't use fetch.  The method itself is used in the render of a page.  For example, something like this:
export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { cardid: string } }) {
  console.log('IN card/[cardid]/page pate.tsx with ', params);
  const cardData = await getDataForCard(params.cardid);
  return (
    <main>
      <h2>
        In Card {params.cardid} and data = {cardData.id}
      </h2>
    </main>
  );
}


Problem
In the provided repository, you invoke cached function in two places - within Page component and in generateMetadata function. React cache wrapper caches output for given parameters only if it's called within React component.
In other words, React caches function call within Page, but not within generateMetadata. Please, keep in mind that React cache is still experimental and most likely will change in the future, so I would refrain from using it in a reall application (even though Next team pushes towards using it now).
Possible solution (not working for async calls)
You can build your own cache manager, which would work for both generateMetadata and Page component. This solution worked for code in your repository
// database.ts
export class CacheManager {
  private static cache = new Map<string, string>();
  public static getDataForCard(id: string) {
    const fromCache = Manager.cache.get(id);
    if (fromCache) return { id: fromCache };
    // Some logic goes here
    Manager.cache.set(id, id);
    return { id: id };
  }
}

// page.tsx
const cardData = Manager.getDataForCard(params.cardid);

This will only work if getDataForCard is a synchronous function. For async functions it's different.
Problem with async functions / methods
Next.js builds static pages concurrently. So if getDataForCard returns a Promise, Next would not wait for it to resolve when processing other pages. To make it work for async behaviour, we should keep track of calls with the same arguments.
Solution for async calls
My proposed solution is heavily inspired by the Meta's Memcache lease technique (described in 3.2.1). Alongside with cache you should keep track of pending calls. Algorithm could be descibed as follows:

First page makes first call of getDataForCard method with id argument
This method checks whether given id is stored in the cache. If so - just return cached value
If id is not present in cache, we fetch needed data (in this case it's a Firestore request)
Then second call with the same id is waiting until first is finished. This is why we need to keep track of pending requests
When first call is finished, it updates the cache
Then all pending and following calls get data from the cache

And here's the code for this solution:
export class CacheManager {
  // Here we store data cache
  private static cache = new Map<string, CardData>();
  // Map of pending requests with id as key and array of functions as value
  private static pendingRequests = new Map<string, Cb[]>();
  // Method to call firestore (or whatever service)
  public static async fetchDataForCard(id: string): Promise<CardData> {
    // Firestore logic goes here
  }
  
  public static async getDataForCard(id: string): Promise<CardData> {
    // Step 1. Check if data in cache exists
    const fromCache = CacheManager.cache.get(id);
    // If data exists in cache - just return it
    if (fromCache) {
      return { id: fromCache };
    }
    
    // Step 2. Check if method was previously called with the same id
    // and if there are pending requests
    const oldPendingRequests = CacheManager.pendingRequests.get(id);
    // If so - add current call to pending requests list
    if (oldPendingRequests) {
      return new Promise<CardData>((resolve) => {
        const cb = (data: CardData) => {
          resolve(data);
        };
        // All callbacks in this list would be handled on
        // Step 5 of the first call
        CacheManager.pendingRequests.set(id, [...oldPendingRequests, cb]);
      });
    }
    // Initialize list if it's first call
    if (!oldPendingRequests) {
      CacheManager.pendingRequests.set(id, [])
    }

    // Step 3. Make async request call
    const cardData = await CacheManager.fetchDataForCard(id);
    
    // Step 4. Update cache
    CacheManager.cache.set(id, cardData);

    // Step 5. Check again for pending requests
    const pendingRequests = CacheManager.pendingRequests.get(id);
    // if present - call them with data
    if (pendingRequests) {
      pendingRequests.forEach((promise) => {
        promise(cardData);
      });
    }

    // Step 5. Return data for the first call
    return cardData;
  }
}

Optimization
Under the hood, React cache uses Least recently used cache replacement policy. So if you're looking for something like this in terms of memory optimization, you may use 3 party library, such as lru-cache
Notes
Also in my examples I get the value from Map directly via get. It would make more sense to check the existence of key in cache with has, something like:
if (cache.has(id)) return { id: cache.get(id) }

but TS always expects possible undefined value as output of get, since it's signature is
get(key: K): V | undefined;

So the compiler would force you to validate the value anyway.

Sadly, that doesn't seem to work.   You'd think it would, but I've updated the repo, and if you do a npm run build you'll see it fails.  If you remove the sleep (or network connection) it will work - there's something in the internals of next.js doing multiple concurrent page builds, which causes each cache hit to fail.
(Or I made a mistake)

You're right - initial solution did not work with async calls. I've updated the answer to handle async logic.It would be great if you could try it, before bounty is expired (there are 11 hours left)

Okay, I see what you're doing - basically building a concurrent access singleton cache class.  I guess there must be a library for this - can you recommend one (which also does concurrent access handling).  As for your solution, a small problem in the resolve (I think it should be  resolve({ id: data });), but I think this works.  Thank you Vladyslav!

(You also need a CacheManager.cache.set, perhaps as part of fetchDataForCard)

That's right! It's basically a singleton, which handles concurrent calls. As for libraries, I did not use it myself, but perhaps lockfile may be useful. You can create lock on first call and wait for unlock on later calls. Also good call on setting cache, I'll update the answer
